# How Can i Remove all sidebars from specific wordpress pages?

Tags: php, wordpress

hi everyone im trying to remove all of the sidebars from a specific video page im creating on a wordpress site ive found tutorials on google on how to do this if the sidebars are called to the page using the

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

method however my theme uses  following method  to call sidebars to a page

```
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/sidebar.php");?>
```

i cant find any good methods for removing the sidebars that calls them to a page the same way as my theme does. here is the code to my page.php file on my website any help understanding how to remove them would be  greatly appreciated =)

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="breadcrumb"><?php breadcrumbs(); ?></div>
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/sidebar.php");?>
<div id="kontenutama">
  <div class="postingan">
  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <?php the_title(); ?></a></h2><?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
  <br style="clear:both;">
  </div>
</div>
<?php include(TEMPLATEPATH."/r_sidebar.php");?>
<br style="clear:both"><div style="clear:both">
</div>
<?php get_footer()?>
```

Comment: Just remove the lines that add the side bars...

Comment: why not just remove them from your page via the wordpress admin page? Isnt it true that they supply a way to change them from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not create a new [WordPress page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates) and remove the sidebar include on that page?

The theme is pretty dodgy, it shouldn't ever include files like that in template pages.

Comment: hi thanks for the response =) thats a perfect solution ive heard of custom page templates before but i never looked into it and yah the theme is a pretty crazy one ive just been customizing it for practice it can be seen here http://test.smartphonesource.org/ im just using it to learn wordpress customization and get the feel for molding a wordpress site ill be implementing this method for removing the sidebars thanks =)